# Testing in React with preloadedState: redux store gets out of sync when having a manual import of store in a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests for React using react-testing-library and jest and are having some problems figuring out how to set a preloadedState for my redux store, when another file imports the store.

I Have a function to set up my store like this

**store.ts**

```js
  export const history = createBrowserHistory()
  export const makeStore = (initalState?: any) => configureStore({
    reducer: createRootReducer(history),
    preloadedState: initalState
  })
  export const store = makeStore()
```

and another js file like this

**utils.ts**

```js
  import store from 'state/store'
  const userIsDefined = () => {
    const state = store.getState()
    if (state.user === undefined) return false
    ...
    return true
  }
```

I then have a test that looks something like this:

**utils.test.tsx** (the renderWithProvider is basically a render function that also wraps my component in a Render component, see: https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components)

```js
  describe("Test", () => {
    it("Runs the function when user is defined", async () => {
      const store = makeStore({ user: { id_token: '1' } })
      const { container } = renderWithProvider(
        <SomeComponent></SomeComponent>,
        store
      );
    })
  })
```

And the <SomeComponent> in turn calls the function in **utils.ts**

**SomeComponent.tsx**

```js
  const SomeComponent = () => {
    if (userIsDefined() === false) return (<Forbidden/>)
    ...
  }
```

Now.. What happens when the test is run seem to be like this.

1. **utils.ts** is read and reads the line **import store from 'state/store'**, this creates and saves a store variable where the user has not yet been defined.
2. the **utils.test.tsx** is called and runs the code that calls **const store = makeStore({ user: { id_token: '1' } })**.
3. The **renderWithProvider()** renderes **SomeComponent** which in turn calls the **userIsDefined** function.
4. The **if (state.user === undefined)** returns false because **state.user** is still undefined, I think that's because **utils.ts** has imported the store as it were before I called my own **makeStore({ user: { id_token: '1' } })**?

---

The answer I want:
I want to make sure that when call makeStore() again it updates the previously imported version of store that is being used in **utils.ts**. Is there a way to to this without having to use **useSelector()** and pass the user value from the component to my utils function?

e.g I could do something like this, but I'd rather not since I have a lot more of these files and functions, and rely much on **import store from 'state/store'**:

SomeComponent.tsx

```js
  const SomeComponent = () => {
    const user = useSelector((state: IState) => state.user)
    if (userIsDefined(user) === false) return (<Forbidden/>)
    ...
  }
```

utils.ts

```js
  //import store from 'state/store'
  const userIsDefined = (user) => {
    //const state = store.getState()
    if (user === undefined) return false
    ...
    return true
  }
```

As I said above I'd prefer not to do it this way.

---

(btw I can't seem to create a fiddle for this as I don't know how to do that for tests and with this use case)

Thank you for any help or a push in the right direction.

Comment: How and where exactly are you calling those utils? In general: yes, stuff like that is why you usually should not randomly import your state into other files. You can just jest to mock the full store file, but that's a pain.

Comment: Well the utils file are used by lots of other files, and yeah I wouldnt like to mock the full store. Maybe there's a way to update the state of the store, without having to call makeStore again...? have not been able to figure that one out though.

Comment: How are they used? Only in components? Somewhere else? Give some examples. You *will* probably have to restructure some of your code somewhere as right now you've created untestable code with a "global variable dependency".

Comment: Generally though: you should **never** call a method that imports the store from the side within a component. The component will not change when the state updates. Essentially you are just uncovering a bug in your application right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just uncovering a bug in your application: you are using direct access to `store` inside a react component, which is something you should *never* do. Your component will not rerender when that state changes and get out of sync.

If you really want a helper like that, make a custom hook out of it:

```js
  import store from 'state/store'
  const useUserIsDefined = () => {
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
    if (user === undefined) return false
    ...
    return true
  }
```

That way your helper does not need direct access to `store` and the component will rerender correctly when that store value changes.

Comment: Ah thank you, I might look into the idea of making a custom hook out of this

Comment: If you want to improve the rerendering behaviour, make the test in the selector:
`const useUserIsDefined = () => useSelector(state => state.user !== undefined )`

That will only rerender when the value goes from `true` to `false` or other way round instead of every time `state.user` changes.

Comment: Using a custom hook like you described seems to work perfectly. even when I call makeStore() again it detects the changes and makes my tests pass. Thank you